# Azure AD Authentication remembers selected account. How to stop this

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

To authenticate with AzureAD I put the folling Code in an Console Application

```
private static async Task<string> GetAuthTokenAsync(string tendent,string AppIdUri , string ClientID)
    {
        /*
         <add key="ida:Audience" value="https://mehler.ws/ToDoWebApi" />
<add key="ida:ClientID" value="f0e91727-3edd-4b00-9630-591166a74e4b" />
        */
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format("https://login.windows.net/{0}", tendent));
        AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireToken(AppIdUri, ClientID , new Uri(Settings.Default.WebApiReplyAdress));

        return result.CreateAuthorizationHeader();
    }
```

the Method AcquireToken Shows a Screen where I am asked to Input my Credentials.

I accidently selected the Account I log in with in Windows 10. Now the Screen doesn't show up any more an the application uses my Windows 10 Account automatically. Does anyone know how to fix this Problem, so that the Screen shows up again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Token's are cached to alleviate complexity in your app. You will need to clear the token cache if you want the user to log back in... typically you would setup a logout function.

More information on token cache: http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/01/getting-acquainted-with-adals-token-cache/

How to logout:

```
authContext.TokenCache.Clear();
string requestUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri={1}";
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUrl);
    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
});
```

- {0} - Fully qualified name of your Azure Active Directory e.g.
  yourad.onmicrosoft.com or tenant id.
- {1} - The URL of your application where a user must be redirected
  back after the logout is complete. This should be properly URL
  encoded.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to pass to AcquireToken PromptBehavior.Always, there's an overload for that. That will cause ADAL to ignore the cache and will ask the service for a clean prompt

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple Solution myself to once clear the Cache.
Delete Cookies in Internet Explorer / Edge ;-)

Thanks anyway for the Answers hot to implement proper Logout Code and Force Prompt for Login allways.